# Is it possible to load items from an Enum to a ComboBox in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, combobox, enums

Is it possible to load items from an Enum to a ComboBox in .NET 3.5?

Comment: WinForms? ASP.Net? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: WinForms, your solution worked. :D THanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

```
combobox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));
```

Comment: @Adam: Thanks; you beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: Oh how nice! Such useful things in .NET!

Comment: To complete answer, to get the value you do myVariable = (SomeEnum) comboBox1.SelectedValue;

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code we used on a recent project.  It handles localized Enum strings (by passing in a `ResourceManager` object) and populates the `.Items` array directly instead of using a DataSource -- this is useful for populating a `ComboBox`, including setting its `.SelectedItem`, before making it or its parent controls visible.

```
public static void PopulateComboBox<T>(ComboBox box, ResourceManager res) {
    box.FormattingEnabled = true;
    ListControlConvertEventHandler del = delegate(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e) {
        e.Value = res.GetString(e.Value.ToString());
    };
    box.Format -= del;
    box.Format += del;
    box.BeginUpdate();
    box.Items.Clear();
    foreach(T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
        box.Items.Add(value);
    }
    box.EndUpdate();
}
```

Use it like:

```
PopulateComboBox<MyEnum>(myComboBox, MyEnumStrings.ResourceManager);
```